# Yajurvedic Shradha Vidhi and deep -dana?

Tags: vedas, yajur-veda

As we know dwija perform various vedic rituals based on **Grihya sutra** according to vedas followed by them. I'm interested to know which chapter (Adhyaaya) of yajurveda explains about it.